# How to add a custom cell of uitableviewcell type as tableview header?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom tableview cell used in many different table Views. Now, my requirement is to use the same tableview cell as a header in one of the table view. But the problem that I am facing is, I don't want to change anything in the custom table cell but while building the cells of the tableview I want to add the header view in it.
Currently, What I am doing is something like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let model = model as? AParticularModel {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellHeader", for: indexPath) as? CustomCellHeader {
            cell.configure(tit: model.title)
            cell.delegate = self
            tableView.tableHeaderView = cell.contentView
        }
       if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell") as? TableCell {
            cell.configureCell(with: model.data[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
   }
```

Currently the issues are:

1. TableHeader is taking a lot of space for which I am not sure how to assign height
2. TableHeader has a button which is not clickable.

Comment: cell can't be headerview. I have implemented headerview with custom height. What issue you are facing in it.

Comment: if we do something like this:  let headerView = UIView(), headerView.addSubview(cell) will this work ?

Comment: In func rowHeight you can set height for Header cell with indexpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **UITableViewDelagates and Datasource** functions for the sections.

Try this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

      if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellHeader") as? CustomCellHeader {
            cell.configure(tit: model.title)
            cell.delegate = self
      return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 30
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 110
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return anyArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell") as? TableCell {
            cell.configureCell(with: model.data[indexPath.row])

            return cell
        }
}
```

You can add number of sections according to your choice and also can set the header's cell and the other's cell height separately.

Comment: for: indexPath in viewforheaderinsection gives error

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik you have to use **indexPath.section** in viewForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 1):

As you know , giving a headerview to tableview's is generally use for fix a view to spesific section . If you use it in cell , when you scroll down tableview , your header is not gonna appear until you scroll to top.If you want to do this behaviour , It's better to use sections instead of headerview.

Anyway , you can use below code to make a headerview from customcell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellHeader") as? CustomCellHeader {
     cell.configure(tit: model.title)
     cell.delegate = self
     return cell
}
```

and for height

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return yourDesireHeight
}
```